# RoboVM: missing signing identity

Tags: ios, xcode, libgdx, robovm

I have an app developed using libGDX and porting to iOS using robovm. This was working perfectly. I then updated my provisioning profile to allow export to another device. When doing this, I was now getting 2 provisioning profiles with the same name listed in robovm, so I used 'iPhone configuration utility' to delete them and then readded the provisioning profile. Now, when I look in xCode it shows my provisioning profile, my signing ID etc all perfectly fine. If I run the command "security find-identity -v -p codesigning" it lists my signing ID perfectly fine. But in eclipse when I go to RoboVM > Package for App STore/Ad Hoc distribution the Signing Identity dropdown no long contains my ID and if I try to enter it manually it can't find it.

I have checked my keychain and I have the certificate in there. I have tried restarting both xcode and eclipse multiple times. This was all working perfectly before I used iphone configuration utility.

Comment: Let us know the RoboVM version you are using and the output from "security". There was a bug in 0.0.14 and earlier related to revoked certificates: https://github.com/robovm/robovm/issues/392. If "security" shows certs with the flag CSSMERR_TP_CERT_REVOKED you should use Keychain Access to delete them and then retry with RoboVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the gradle setup (which you should) then open up your build.gradle file (in the ios project, NOT the root file) and put this at the bottom of the file:

```
robovm {
iosSignIdentity = "your signing identity"
iosProvisioningProfile = "your provisioning profile"
iosSkipSigning = false
stdoutFifo = ""
stderrFifo = ""
```

}

Just put in the names exactly as they are named in the developer center.

This might then work through eclipse's roboVM export option but if it doesn't then go to your project folder with the commandline and run:

```
gradlew ios:createIPA
```

or if on MacOSX

```
./gradlew ios:createIPA
```

and if you don't have permissions to use ./gradle you need to add permissions for it using:

```
chmod +x ./gradlew
```

Comment: What do you put in the provisioning profile section? There are lots of IDs I could use, not sure what is expected.